# SATA turn into external not detected on finder

Tags: mac, hard-drive, imac

I just upgrade my iMac drive from SATA to SSD, so i buy this External Case for SATA and put my old drive into it, the problem is now my imac cannot detect the SATA (turn into external drive) on finder, but when i open disk utility the drive is detected, any tips what should i do to browse the drive on finder without erase it first?[image]

Comment: If it was wokring *internally* fine and not working *externally* on the same Mac then I would tend to blame the cable, internal connector or the electronics in the external case, as I have done this many times and it works a treat.

Comment: What does the output from `diskutil info disk3 | grep Size` show?